# Custom MOTD without changing prompt colors

Tags: cmdline.txt, file

I happened to stumble on [this forum thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=23440) (and every other page I find on RPi MOTD links here), and found a nice description on how to change the MOTD. However, after creating a `/home/pi/.bash_profile` file and using even the simplest code such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(tput setaf 2)
   .~~.   .~~.
  '. \ ' ' / .'$(tput setaf 1)
   .~ .~~~..~.
  : .~.'~'.~. :
 ~ (   ) (   ) ~
( : '~'.~.'~' : )
 ~ .~ (   ) ~. ~
  (  : '~' :  ) $(tput sgr0)Raspberry Pi$(tput setaf 1)
   '~ .~~~. ~'
       '~'
$(tput sgr0)"
```

from [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=78678#p78678), my prompt becomes always white, instead of remaining colored.

What should/can be added to print a nice color ASCII picture and still have colored prompts/text?

EDIT: It turns out that so much as having a `.bash_profile` file will cause this. Is there no way around it?

Also: Sorry about the tags. Not sure what to use, but not enough rep to create new ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in *man bash*

```
   When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading  that  file,  it
   looks  for  ~/.bash_profile,  ~/.bash_login,  and  ~/.profile,  in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.
```

By default on raspberry ~/.profile  is executed which in turn executes ~/.bashrc (giving you fancy colors) and adding local bin directories to PATH (which comes in handy).

again reminder from ~/.profile

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
```

And so we arrive to solution to your problem:
add this line to the beginning of the ~/.bash_profile file

```
. "$HOME/.profile"
```